# What does a prime mean in a node label in a X-bar structure tree?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

In Anderson's Essentials of Linguistics, a X-bar structure tree contains nodes labeled with `'`. What does the prime mean? What do `N'`, `V'`, and `T'` mean? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's the "bar" in "X-bar".

Comment: Anderson et al. (2nd ed.), “ So not only do all heads have phrases, and all phrases have heads, but there is what we might call a “mid sized sub-phrase” in every phrase (or an “intermediate phrase”). This mid-sized phrase is called X-bar (written X’), which is where the theory gets its name.” https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/essentialsoflinguistics2/chapter/x-bar-theory-introduction/

Answer (score 2):

This is simply an alternative way of writing the eponymous X-bar itself — back in the day, `X'` was sometimes easier than typewriting `X̄`.

This should be clear from context from a vague understanding of the theory.